# I'm getting error when I use conditional operation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I've written a line using a conditional operator as shown below:

```
assign {RS2, RS1} = (!DisM || !DisX)? (RdEn==2'b00? (!DisI? {rs2, rs1} : 64'bz) : (RdEn==2'b01? (!switch? {rs2, Rn} : {Rn, rs1}) : {Rm, Rn}))) : 64'bz;
```

1. RS2 & RS1 are 32 bit output wires.
2. Rn & Rm are 32 bit inputs.
3. rs1 & rs2 are 32 bit registers.
4. RdEn is 2bit register.
5. DisI and switch are one bit register.

[image]

The simulator (Icarus 0.9.7 or any) is showing there is a syntax error in the above line.

Here is my code which addresses the same problem:

```
module TEST(Rn, Rm, DisM, DisX, DisI, switch, RdEn, RS1, RS2);
input [31:0]Rn, Rm;
input DisM, DisX, DisI, switch;
input [1:0]RdEn;
output [31:0]RS1, RS2;

reg [31:0]rs1, rs2;

always@*
begin
    rs1 = Rn + 32'd7;
    rs2 = Rm - 32'd7;
end

assign {RS2, RS1} = (!DisM || !DisX)? (RdEn==2'b00? (!DisI? {rs2, rs1} : {64{1'bz}}) : (RdEn==2'b01? (!switch? {rs2, Rn} : {Rn, rs1}) : {Rm, Rn}))) : {64{1'bz}};

endmodule
```

Comment: Your line 338 is super confusing with so many conditionals. Why not split it up? That would make clearer code for understanding and debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler interpreted the `?` in `RdEn==2'b00?` as a 3rd bit instead of as the ternary operator.  Just add a space between `b00` and `?`.  Same for `b01?`.

`?` is a valid z_digit.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 5.7 Numbers.

Also, you had a mismatched number of parentheses (a good editor can show this):

```
assign {RS2, RS1} = (!DisM || !DisX)? (RdEn==2'b00 ? (!DisI? {rs2, rs1} : {64{1'bz}}) : (RdEn==2'b01 ? (!switch? {rs2, Rn} : {Rn, rs1}) : {Rm, Rn})) : {64{1'bz}};
```

It is also good practice to use `{64{1'bz}}` to make sure you get 64 bits of `1'bz`.

Answer (score 1):

Though you already got an accepted answer, I would highly recommend you re-code assignment. As is, it is hard to read and thereby hard to debug. At minimum add return lines and indent so the conditions are easy to visually pair. For example, the following is a copy of toolic's solution with added newlines and spaces. Notice how the `RdEn==2'b00?` issue cannot happen with this formatting style. Editors like emacs and vim have syntax plugins that can help with indent formatting.

```
assign {RS2, RS1} = (!DisM || !DisX)
  ? (RdEn==2'b00
    ? (!DisI ? {rs2, rs1} : {64{1'bz}})
    : (RdEn==2'b01
        ? (!switch ? {rs2, Rn} : {Rn, rs1})
        : {Rm, Rn}))
  : {64{1'bz}};
```

In practice I find the conditional operator `?:` (w/o high-Z) usually makes explicit 2:1 muxs when synthesizing, which may not optimal for timing and area. I also find keeping tri-state assignments simple gives cleaner results.

The approach I usually recommend is to determine output enable and output data separate from the tri-state assignment. Synthesizers usually do better job with this approach than one long assign statement; at least from my experience. This approach is also good if you have a limited number tri-state drivers, which is common for FPGAs.

```
wire out_en = (!DisM || !DisX) && !(RdEn==2'b00 && !DisI);
reg [63:0] out_data;
always @* begin
  case(RdEn)
    2'b00 : out_data = {rs2, rs1};
    2'b01 : out_data = !switch ? {rs2, Rn} : {Rn, rs1});
    default : out_data = {Rm, Rn};
  endcase
end
assign {RS2, RS1} = out_en ? out_data : {64{1'bz}};
```

Occasionally parallel tri-state drivers with non-overlapping enable does better job at meeting some design criteria. This approach can reduce timing depending on the technology-node and architecture. There is usually an area hit and it could negatively impact the timing if there is to much loading.

```
assign {RS2, RS1} = ((!DisM || !DisX) && RdEn==2'b00 && !DisI)   ? {rs2, rs1} : {64{1'bz}};
assign {RS2, RS1} = ((!DisM || !DisX) && RdEn==2'b01 && !switch) ? {rs2,  Rn} : {64{1'bz}};
assign {RS2, RS1} = ((!DisM || !DisX) && RdEn==2'b01 &&  switch) ? { Rn, rs1} : {64{1'bz}};
assign {RS2, RS1} = ((!DisM || !DisX) && RdEn[1])                ? { Rm,  Rn} : {64{1'bz}};
```

Regardless of the approach used, make sure the enable control of the tri-state is glitch free. If the signal is not clean it can cause contention on the bus. Ideally the enable signal should be direct flop. A flopped enable signal is not always feasible in practice, so you need to keep an eye on it. You typically will not see potential glitches in RTL simulation. You synthesis report might have some insight if there is an issue.